# How to calculate the statistical uncertainty in a particle physics simulation?

Tags: statistics, physics, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics, monte-carlo

I have a Monte Carlo code which simulates ions in a [Tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak). Most of the particles remain trapped forever. However, some of the particles escape. I can use my code to predict the fraction of particles that escape versus those that stay trapped. The code models collisions using a stochastic collision operator. Therefore, there is a statistical uncertainty with my results. Do you know any techniques to calculate this statistical uncertainty?

One idea I had is to use the [Bootstrapping technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). I'll quickly explain my plan now:

Suppose we have $N$ trapped particles and $n<N$ that escape. We denote the particles that are trapped with $t_i$ (for $i\in\{1,2,...,N\}$) and the ones that escape with $e_i$ (for $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$). Hence, the estimate for the fraction of markers that escape is $n/(n+N)$. To calculate the uncertainty, we make a list which looks like the following:
$$\{t_1,t_2,...,t_N,e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}.$$
We resample this list (with replacement) $m$ times (e.g. $m=100$) to produce lists which may look something like this:
$$\underbrace{\{t_{36}, e_{12}, t_{444}, t_{321},...\}}_{n+N\ \mathrm{elements}}.$$
Then calculate the fraction of markers which escape for each of the $m$ cases and take away $n/(n+N)$ to produce a list of values with length $m$. Finally, take, e.g. a 95% quantile of this to get a 95% confidence interval.

Can you see any problems with this method? Is there a more straightforward method I could be using? I know barely any statistics, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you simulate the outcome (escaped/trapped ratio) after a specific time $T$ many times over independently (i.e. loop the code a lot of times)? If yes, all the standard theory of Monte Carlo applies (central limit, variance reduction, etc)

Comment: Yes, I can loop the code lots of times. However, it's very computationally expensive to do so. Can you point me towards a good book or website on Monte Carlo theory that would be relevant? Are you saying that I may be able to use a simple formula instead of having to resample the data?

Comment: it would be better if you posted a detailed question asking for references in Monte Carlo methods in physics (maybe referring to your particular issue of computational expensive simulations) using the tag 'reference-request'. I am sure some experts could show up. In this case (physics + computational issues) I don't have sufficient expertise.